# error page in web.xml giving 404

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml

In one of my project, I need to handle the 404(Resource not found) and 403(Access Denied). I am giving the configuration in web.xml as

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB_INF/jsp/web/exception/weberror.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/WEB_INF/jsp/web/exception/accessDenied.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</error-page>
```

Now when the access denied generates, browser is showing me native 404. I also remove the friendly error page setting in browser but on removing that I am getting a blank page.

My jsps are in WEB-INF folder. The path where all jsps are places is

```
/WEB_INF/jsp/
```

Please help me out. If I am missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's about using `WEB-INF` instead of `WEB_INF` in your web.xml ?

Comment: HI Roland,Thank you very much. I was duffer and was mistaking - with _. after replacing WEB_INF with WEB-INF, this works. Now I am able to see my own access denied and 404 page.

Answer (score 9):

Files under `/WEB-INF/` are protected from direct access by the client, this is [defined in the Java EE specification](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html#bnadz). So your error pages will have to reside outside this directory. Try moving them to a dedicated location, e. g. `/errors/404.jsp`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using WEB_INF instead of WEB-INF.
all the resources mentioned under WEB-INF are protected from client and cannot be directly accessed so its always a good practice to move it out of the WEB-INF.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error pointed above looks on web.xml as cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'location'.

```
<error-page><location>/error</location></error-page>
```

Error which it generates is

> {"java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":error-code,
>   "java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":exception-type} is expected.

It is correct that avoidance of mapping specific error code with error page has started with servlet 3.0 specification so I got it resolved with the following change:
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd version=3.0

Look at the **version change** from anything to **3.0**